# Flutter Emulator

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying launch the flutter emulator but i'm getting multiple errors like:

> E/flutter (17181): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(143)] Could not prepare isolate.
> E/flutter (17181): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(385)] Could not create root isolate.
> E/flutter (17181): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(604)] Could not launch engine with configuration.

Because i wasn't finding any solution on the internet, i decided to completly re-install flutter in my computer, it worked for the first 2 or 3 times, but right after i started to get again this errors(displayed above).

Why i'm having all these errors?

```
import 'package:first_app/widget/expenses.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    main() {
      runApp(
        MaterialApp(
          home: const Expenses(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android studio then do this:
File -> Invalidate Caches.

If the following solution does not work then try to reinstall the emulator again. Remove data manually if needed from .android/avd and delete all the emulators existing in the folder and try making a new emulator.

Comment: @Ahmed Ashour thank you for your feedback. I'm using VS Code. I did delete all the emulators directly from .android/avd but unfortunately the errors persist.

Comment: Okay, I will look for more solutions. If I can then I will definitely provide you with one.